# Is mocking functionality available for Microsoft Fakes?

Tags: microsoft-fakes, moles

With the inclusion of Microsoft Fakes in Visual Studio 11, I thought it would be worth to look into again, since I did not find Moles mature enough last i checked. The documentation is still sparse, but I cannot find any reference to mocks, i.e. the ability to set up and verify expectations on the faked objects.

Does anyone know if this is currently included (as a feature in the library) or will be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not included currently, but we are considering something in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Although they are not included, you can use stubs to hack in the same behavior.  In your stub you can capture whether the method was called and the parameters that were called.  Of course, by the time you start doing that you're almost hand rolling your own mocks.

In the meantime I'd suggest Moq or RhinoMocks.  I find the syntax simpler and I'm not a fan of the generated code that Microsoft Fakes uses anyhow.  Try renaming a method on one of your fakes using a refactoring tool.  It's not possible because your fake is a generated class, not an instance of the interface you are stubbing.

Comment: Example how to do it manually see http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/11/29/visual-studio-2012-fakes-part-3/